# error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to return a `unique_ptr` from
a vector of base class pointers to apply `polymorphism`
as `unique_ptr` can not be copied.
Is there any way around this?
See `he` function.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class shape {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class circle : public shape {
public:
  virtual void foo() override {cout << "I am circle" << endl;}
};

class square : public shape {
public:
  virtual void foo() override {cout << "I am square" << endl;}
};

unique_ptr<shape> da(int x) {
  if(x)
    return make_unique<circle>();
  return make_unique<square>();
}

unique_ptr<shape> he(const vector<unique_ptr<shape>> &t, int x) {
  return t[x];
}
```

Comment: If you want to copy a smart pointer then `unique_ptr` might not be the correct solution.

Comment: then the only way is to use raw pointers, right?

Comment: Side note: The combination of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` often turns out to be an unforced error. You should avoid both of them individually ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) but when you combine them... Zoinks.

Comment: @user4581301
the real program is very large.
this is just a source I use for competitive programming

Comment: No worries. Just be really really careful and make sure you have precompiled headers set up correctly otherwise you'll find `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` starts costing you time.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks a lot the links are very informative

Comment: Does the receiver have any ownership stake in the pointed-at object? Can it possibly outlive the object inside the `vector` referred to by `t`? If both are no, you're right. Raw pointer. Otherwise consider `shared_ptr`.

Comment: ***then the only way is to use raw pointers, right*** No that is incorrect. There are other ways depending on your needs.

Comment: With reference to function `he`, what are the ownership semantics for the `unique_ptr` you pass in?  If you can clarify that in your own mind you should be able to decide how best to modify the signature of that function such that it (a) compiles, and (b) does the right thing.  Or if you can't decide how to do that, then add a description of said ownership semantics to your question (you might want to guarantee that the underlying pointer remains alive until the caller is done with it, for example) and you should then get better targeted responses.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy a `unique_ptr`. Here's a couple of options

Return a regular pointer

```
shape* he(const vector<unique_ptr<shape>> &t, int x) {
  return t[x].get();
}
```

Return a reference to the unique_ptr

```
const unique_ptr<shape>& he(const vector<unique_ptr<shape>> &t, int x) {
  return t[x];
}
```

Hard to say which is right (if any), but they should both compile.

Comment: Or, just get rid of `he()` altogether, and just have the caller index into the vector directly.